# Multiple instances of angular service objects getting created

Tags: angularjs, service

I am pretty new to Angular and started to create a sample workflow.
I have a angular service that authenticates user and preserves the logged-in user details.

**Edit:**
I have two seperate html pages as a whole, does that create a problem of creating two instances.

```
studentApp.factory("loginService", function(){
    this.loggedUser="Guest!";
    return{
        checkCredentials : function(user){
            //Authenticating logic goes here.
            this.loggedUser =user.username; 
        }
    };
});
```

After a successful login a home page is displayed and it outputs the logged-in user name on the html page, by accessing the service again.

```
studentApp.controller("headerController", ["loginService", function(loginService){
      var vm = this;
      vm.loggedUser = loginService.loggedUser;
}]);
```

But it seems like 'Guest' is being displayed rather than the user name.
I feel that a new service instance is being created.

Comment: when are you calling 'checkCredentials ' function? It will set new user name

Comment: It is called when the login form is submitted ng-submit="lc.formSubmitted()"

Comment: check what "this" is when the check credentials method is called. I suspect  it might no longer be the service. Try using the annonymous function syntax. This creates a closure which will preserve the "this" from the scope that it is created in.

e.g. replace  "checkCredentials : function(user){" with "checkCredentials : (user) => {"

Comment: The login page and the second page where I show the user information are completley seperate pages, does that create any problem

Answer (score 0):

try using getter method in factory -
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/La2rbjd5/)

example -

```
app.factory("loginService", function(){
  this.loggedUser="Guest!";
  return{
    checkCredentials : function(user){
        //Authenticating logic goes here.
        this.loggedUser =user; 
    },
    getLoggedUser : function(){
       return this.loggedUser;
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using different controller for login and home page. If so, you are using `this` in each controller which creates new instances of services in each controller.

```
studentApp.factory("loginService", function() {
    return {
    loggedUser : "Guest!",
    checkCredentials: function(user) {
            //Authenticating logic goes here.
            this.loggedUser = user.username;
        }
    };
})

studentApp.controller("headerController", ["loginService", function(loginService){

      $scope.loggedUser = loginService.loggedUser;
}]);



studentApp.controller("LoginController", ["loginService", function(loginService){
         //login and then call checkcredentials(); 
          loginService.checkCredentials("name");
    }]);
```